# How to download full report in Voximplant?

Tags: voximplant

I got the report data via the downloadStatReport api, but there is a problem. The campaign(33771) has 244 pages data, but I got only 60 lines data, why?
report id is 877036

And the parameters of the API exportStatReport are:

```
String campaignId = ""33771"";  
String from = ""2022-04-28 08:00:00"";  
String to = ""2022-04-28 16:20:00"";
```

The request:

```
curl -X GET https://kitapi-eu.voximplant.com/api/v3/attempt/downloadStatReport?report_id=877036&domain=tannyleung&access_token=xxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

Your time zone is +8 hours.
With api request, the time should be UTC, that is, if you subtract 8 hours from your request, you will receive a correct report.
Example:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data "datetime_start=2022-04-28%2000%3A00%3A00&datetime_end=2022-04-28%2008%3A20%3A00&call_direction=all&campaign_ids=[33771]&format=xlsx&domain=tannyleung&access_token=token" 
"https://kitapi-eu.voximplant.com/api/v3/history/exportCallsHistoryReport"
```